# Pass data via ajax using link_to to rails controller?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to pass an object instance carrying data to the controller using ajax via link_to in a rails project. But my data does not seem to be getting carried to the controller, what have I done wrong? **My code sample is below:**

```
<%= link_to '', my_path_controller_path(my_object: @object),
                              remote: true, method: :post, class: "my-class" %>
```

**In the controller I have the following:**

```
def my_path
    @my_object = MyObject.new(params[:my_object])

        if @my_object.valid?
           @my_object.doSomething()
           render json: {
               success: true
           }
       else
           render json: {
           success: false,
           message: @my_object.errors.full_messages.to_sentence
         }
       end
end
```

@object is an instance variable initialized before it is passed down to the view.

Comment: can you post your full controller action and the params hash that gets sent to the controller?

Comment: I think if you'd `puts params` in controller you can easily find your param.

Comment: The problem is my ajax success is always false because none of the properties on my_object are set, they are all blank. Even though in the view they are all valid on the object instance variable?

Comment: Why don't you put full code but revise it later? The question is totally different with different code. Waste of my time to answer.

Comment: if your using form_for on the page where you make the ajax request to submit a form (if you are you should have posted that code in your question) then you want to use remote: true in your call to form_for. I am not sure its possible to pass params on a link with method: post

Answer (score 1):

try something like this:

```
<%= link_to 'My Link', javascript::void(0), :class => "my-class" %>
```

Put some script:

```
<script>
$(".my-class").click(function() {
   $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "<%= my_path_controller_path %>",
        data: {my_object: <%= @object %>},
        dataType:'script',
            beforeSend: function(){
                // do whatever you want
            },
            success: function(response){
                // do whatever you want
            }
        });
});
</script>
```